# Razor Pages .Net Core passing a multi-layer JSON object with Children, parents and images back from Mathod

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages .Net Core application where I am making an ajax call back into a method in order to retrieve more records to display on screen:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetTimelineEntries(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

        ApplicationUser currentAppUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        PopulateUsersEntries(currentAppUser);
        GetHookUps(currentAppUser);

        foreach (ApplicationUser appUser in AppUsersList)
        {
            PopulateUsersEntries(appUser);
        }

        // The above code just populates the below Entries list:

        var pagedEntries = Entries
                            .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                            .Take(pageSize);

        return new JsonResult(pagedEntries.Select(a => new
        {
            Comment = a.Comment,
            thumbNailImage = a.Trip.Season.AppUser.ApplicationUserImage.ImageDataThumb,
            IsEstimatedWeight = a.IsEstimatedWeight,
            tripTitle = a.Trip.Title,
            entryImagesCount = a.EntryImages.Count,
            tripSeasonTitle = a.Trip.Season.Title,
            appUserFirstName = a.Trip.Season.AppUser.FirstName,
            appUserLastName = a.Trip.Season.AppUser.LastName,
            entryTime = a.EntryTime.ToShortTimeString() + " - " + a.EntryTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
            isCatch = a.IsCatch,
            entryId = a.ID,
            imagesCount = a.EntryImages.Count,
            firstEntryImage = a.EntryImages.FirstOrDefault(),
            fishSpeciesDescription = a.FishSpecies.Description,
            fishWeightDescription = a.Weight + " " + a.WeightUnit.Description,
            entryImages = a.EntryImages


        }));

        //return new JsonResult(pagedEntries);
        //return new JsonResult(pagedEntries.Select(a => new { results = a }));

    }
```

As you can see, it is returning a JSON object where I am having to SELECT the fields I want from the object to pass them back in a 'flat' JSON object. If I try to pass the whole pagedEntries object back through JSON (`return new JsonResult(pagedEntries);`) I get an error in the AJAX result (with not much info at all to diagnose).

```
$.ajax({
    url: '?handler=TimelineEntries',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()); },
    data: { "pageindex": pageIndex, "pagesize": pageSize },
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;

        if (data != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#container").append("<h2>" +
                    data[i].comment +
                    "</h2 > "
                );
            }
            pageIndex++;
        }
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#progress").show();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $("#progress").hide();
    },
    error: function (e) {
        debugger;
        alert("Error while retrieving data!");
    }
});
```

Is there a better way I am able to pass the object `pagedEntries` back to the partial view AJAX call with all its child objects in tact so I dont have to flatten the results into a 1D JSON object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so when I was able to debug further I found that if I stripped my model back to only include single child objects, it did work fine. The problems I had were:

1. Parent objects were preventing a success (child objects were fine)
2. Large images

For the parents objects I did some research and found I needed to make sure I had the latest `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package installed:

[image]

and that it was correctly referenced in Startup.cs (`public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

Ton ensure I was okay to pass over larger image and video files, this seems to be doing the trick so far (in `web.config`)

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

I am now getting back my full model in the ajax: success function including all Child objects, Parent objects and base64 image strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ToList()`.Here is a working demo with a model which has a child object:

Model:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
        public Course Course { get; set; }



    }
 public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

cshtml(I use 0 as `pageIndex`,2 as `pageSize`,and get request don't need XSRF-TOKEN):

```
<div id="container"></div>
<button onclick="sendajax()">click</button>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        function sendajax() {
            var pageIndex = 0;
            var pageSize = 2;
        $.ajax({
            url: '?handler=TimelineEntries',
            data: { "pageindex": pageIndex, "pagesize": pageSize },
            type: "GET",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;

                if (data != null) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $("#container").append("<h2>" +
                            data[i].age +
                            "</h2 > "
                        );
                    }
                    pageIndex++;
                }
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#progress").show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#progress").hide();
            },
            error: function (e) {
                debugger;
                alert("Error while retrieving data!");
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
}
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetTimelineEntries(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var s = _context.Student.Include(s => s.Course).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(s);

        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Many thanks, I was able to articulate a little more on my actual problem in my answer I have posted not long ago . I should have mentioned that the object is already an IQueryable List.